# Flagging for migration to Stack Overflow declined

Tags: discussion, flagging, migration

I flagged [Split Textarea input text into all textarea box without enter button.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211405/290189) for migration to [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) since that site doesn't appear in the migration path in the close dialog, and only moderators can perform the desired migration.  However, my flag was declined.

[image: declined flag]

As the link to W3 Schools and the first comment suggest, it's a technical question rather than a math one, so it shouldn't have been posted.  Nonetheless, given that it's already there, a usual and helpful suggestion would be to migrate this to another suitable SE site, so that SE doesn't lose content, and that OP would probably receive answers from good hands.  (I've asked some questions on Stack Overflow, and received several great answers.)

If we let it sit there, it's going to be auto-deleted as "RemovedAbandonedClosed" (or deleted by three votes), and that won't add value to the site.

Comment: I think it often works out better to recommend searching the potential migration target for related Questions than to flag for moderator migration.  Esp. if you can link to existing Questions that have the information wanted by OP.

Comment: I was the one handling the flag, and what quid said is correct. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for response.  quid's answer helps us understand the migration process more, and it's a pity that that's not found in the Help Center.

Comment: Related by Jeff Atwood: [Don't. Migrate. Crap.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/241919)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While I did not handle that flag let me still comment on this (more generally).

First, yes, the post is off-topic here, yes, in principle something like this is on-topic on SO, thus one in principle one might consider migration.

However, please keep the following in mind.

- A question that is migrated and then gets put on hold afterwards is something quite problematic. The question must be good "as is". I am not sure that's the case for this post. (For the specific case, note that OP has at least one poorly received question on SO already. They clearly know about the site. I don't know,  but chances are they are question-banned there and that's why they asked it here.)
- In the absence of an answer (or even comments) migration has basically no advantage to delete and re-ask. While a migrated question has less visibility than a new question. The time-stamp persists. In the new-queue on the new site it will never be on top. In a way it's a potential disservice to OP even.

For the most part, I think migration is not really useful for question that did not already created some substantive activity. Just recommend the other site to the poster in a comment and let them proceed. I hardly ever migrate in such a case, especially not to crowded sites.

Generally, while certainly raised in attempts to help, most flags for migration I handle, honestly, I'd prefer they would never have been raised.

Please, only recommend questions for migration that spawned some substantive activity already that cannot be preserved by simply re-asking on the other site. In other cases, recommend the other site in a comment and leave it at that.

Comment: This should be documented in the help center.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: Well, it's in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/275243) at least.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the link. It's noteworthy that the remark regarding the implications of questions  being already answered on migration is somewhat differently explained there. (That's a known issue though, this particular inconsistency. It's also not as big as it might seem on first glance.)